# how to display the multiple column with comma separated?

Tags: php, sql

my table like this

```
projectname  userlist

banking         john
banking         ram
hospital        ramesh
```

i want output like this

```
banking   john,ram
hospital     ramesh
```

Comment: Can you show us your code? Need to know your current structure.

Comment: Where are all these strings coming from?

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript? This is a SQL question...

Comment: What's the RDBMS? MySQL? SQL Server?

Answer (score 3):

**Pure SQL:**

```
SELECT
    projectname
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(userlist) AS userlist
FROM
    projects
GROUP BY
    projectname
```

Comment: This works in MySQL but OP did not specify RDBMS.

Comment: I would hardly call mySQL 'pure', especially its "let's break 1NF" `GROUP_CONCAT` function ;)

Answer (score 0):

> mysql >
>      -> SELECT student_name,
>               ->     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT test_score
>       ->               ORDER BY test_score DESC SEPARATOR ' ')
>       ->     FROM student
>       ->     GROUP BY student_name;

You should take a look into **[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)**.

Previous code taken from [MySQL Reference Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).